# Accessing Spring Boot application properties within Groovy bean DSL

Tags: groovy, spring-boot

The short version: How do I access Spring Boot application properties from my application context?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do. If there is a better or more standard way to do something like this, let me know.

The `application.properties` file:

```
spring.application.name = myApp
spring.profiles.active = dev
```

The `context.groovy` file:

```
import ...
beans {
    name String, ref('spring.application.name')
    env String, ref('spring.application.env')

    otherBean(...) {
        name = name
    }
}
```

I have tried a number of formats that also do not work:

```
name = spring.application.name
name = ref('spring.application.name')
```

I must be missing something fundamental about how to import or access the application properties from within the context configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use it with the place holder syntax (watch out to use single quotes, or else groovy will handle it), e.g.:

```
appName String, '${spring.application.name}'
```

or you have direct access to the `environment` (no `ref` &c needed).  e.g.

```
appName String, environment.getProperty('spring.application.name', 'The Fallback')
```